# What is the meaning of log(0,1)[x] in Mathematica 9.0?

Tags: mathematica

everyone.I want to know the meaning of "log(0,1)[2,x]" in the out[8].What's the difference between log[2,x] and log(0,1)[2,x] in Mathematica?

[image]

Comment: By the way, `xlog[2,x]` $\ne$ `x log[2,x]` $\ne$ `x Log[2,x]`, which is what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

$\log^{(0,1)}[2,x]$ is the partial derivative in respect to the second variable evaluated at $(2,x)$. Please note that you wrote log which is a variable for Mathematica. If you want the logarithm function write Log[x]

On the other hand $\log[2,x]$ is log evaluated at $(2,x)$.